# Helium temperatures and lighter than air aircraft

Tags: science-fiction

This for short story, If you had an airship filled with helium what would happen if you got the gas cold enough that it became a liquid at -452F. Would it still fly?

Since it's semi a solid it would take up less space but would the lighter than air characteristics still work? Or do those depend on temperature?

Comment: Hello Henry. While we answer real-world questions, we still expect you to be asking about the rules of your fictional world. This is simply a chemistry question that boils down to "what is the density of liquid helium and is that density less than that of gaseous air?" which could be and probably should be asked on [chemistry.se], but they may ask why you didn't just google the data. Please take our [tour] and read the first two bullets of our [help] to better understand our Stack. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah I tried looking it up but could not really find anything useful. FYI it is for  fictional world where a special type of helium based cargo transport is used lift heavy cargo into the upper atmosphere. This being done through mixture of powered thrust and Aerostat tech. Don't I won't bother you delicate geniuses again.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @HenryDent I regret that the fact that this (and every other) Stack has rules has put you off. Perhaps you should have read through them before judging us.

Comment: 1st question: Is it a rigid frame or a blimp? 2nd question: Why is the temperature so low? Is it because of the environment or do you have cooling apparatus on board? 3rd: What is the material of your gas container? At that temperature, normal materials would crumble under tensile loads

Comment: Seems like this concept is heading toward https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum_airship

Comment: As others have said we would be glad to help build a world, but this question is simply worded like a "I had a thought one day" physics curiosity. The answer is, no, it would not fly when helium is denser than air. I have to agree with the close votes for now.

Answer (score 3):

Frame challenge..

**At first glance, according to Archimedes, you'd be grounded..**

Air has a density of approximately 1.225 kg/m3

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_of_air

The density of liquid helium-4 is 160.0kg/m3

https://www.aqua-calc.com/calculate/weight-to-volume

**... but nothing would fly, really! ...**

Nitrogen and oxigen have far higher freezing point compared to helium. There will only be solids+vacuum near zero Kelvin, *nothing* would fly in air.

Comment: So much for trying to help a new user to [better understand how to use this Stack](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @JoinJBHonCodidact don't understand your remark, this is a very short frame challenge, no pun intended toward the new user. A mod could move this out to physics or chemistry, but I'm afraid it won't be received well.. it's about aircraft.. and against basic laws of physics.

Comment: I understand your point - but it assumes that everything, everywhere is the same temperature. It's possible to assume from the question that only the helium in the bladder/tank is liquefied, in which case there's no frame challenge. As for my remark - it's important to help people learn how to ask good questions, and this question suffers from item #1 on the page I linked: lack of research. It also suffers for lack of conditions and context. All of that should be resolved before anyone answers.

Comment: @Goodies Your answer is about densities. You tell about freezing point but don't give the numbers. I am giving numbers about freezing points. There are so many books on physics, math, chemistry etc explaining same topics in different ways. Are they copies of each other? Your answer is not your original research. After all it is copy of somebody else's research. Should he give you -ve marks?

Comment: I understand your complaint about my downvote @imtaar but your answer was later, numbers can be easily added.. I didn't end my answer with "if the air was kept gaseous".. I frame-challenged the whole idea, because the opening is about *airships* (which have a balloon hull) not about a temperature-isolated tank. A tank won't float anyway. You can't fill an airship with liquid helium and expect it to *exist* in gaseous air, because the air will be solid, when the  helium in the balloon is liquid.

Answer (score 3):

> Since it's semi a solid it would take up less space but would the
> lighter than air characteristics still work? Or do those depend on
> temperature?

The only reason helium works is because it takes up so much space for its weight. The amount of bouyency you get is proportional to your volume. So you want a large volume and a small weight. Hence big bags of helium. If you use liquid helium, your volume goes way down. The whole point of using helium is lost.

Answer (score -2):

**You cannot float in solid.**

Boiling point of helium is -268.9 °C and melting point is -272.2 °C.

Boiling point of nitrogen (78% of air) is -195.8 °C and melting point is -210 °C °C.

When helium becomes liquid, nitrogen is already solid. How can you float in solid?

**Liquid helium in gaseous air.**

If you liquefy helium only while keeping air gaseous, helium will be heavy. It will not float.

Comment: -1 for copying my answer (lol)